# How to set Application Level role for Entity Framework when hitting database?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, security-roles

Not using migrations. At my company I have the only true access to the DB, anytime anyone else hits it they get denied permission based on Windows Auth, I want to allow anyone who uses my application to be able to hit the DB. I have created an Application Level Role with hopes that my application and whomever is using it will be assigned that Application Role and do the things it is permitted to do.

I was thinking this would be set in my dbContext construction or perhaps app.config. I haven't found any examples of this online which I find strange, seems like a common use case.

Comment: Hi is SQL Server authentication an option? Then u can have a username and password created in DB and let application use that. If your app is a Web app another option is to setup the application pool identity as a user with access to the DB and turn of impersonation if turned on.

Comment: @KofiAmparbeng don't have ability to impersonate. My repo is setup to be a web app and also runs a rich client

Comment: @markokstate is it an asp.net web app ?

Comment: @AntoinePelletier wpf for rich client and asp for web aspect.

Comment: Is there any error message ? because i'm hesitating to say it migth be the connection string, the security level of your bd, or it dosen't allow your web app to connect using  windows auth, i had that problem myself, if so, you have to create a user just like the guys in the first comment